# Set session variable with link_to Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, session, hyperlink

Is it possible to set a session variable with a link_to?  I don't want to set a parameter, because I have a couple redirects and it gets wiped away.

i.e. I want to set a session variable "modelid" to "you" with a link.

I want to set a session variable while the FB login oauth runs...

```
<%= link_to "New Post", "#", {:class => "btn btn-primary btn-large inline pull-left", :onclick => "FB.login(function(response){},{perms:'email, publish_stream, user_photos'});" } %>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create an action in one of your controllers that sets this session variable and then call it with an AJAX request.

routes:

```
post "/myroute", :to=>"some_controller#set_my_session_var"
```

some_view.html.erb (jquery example):

```
$(function(){
  $("#my-button").click(function(){
    $.post('/myroute');
  })
})
```

some_controller.rb:

```
def set_my_session_var
  session[:somekey]='somevalue'
end
```

Comment: I am setting session variable in a controller's method and trying to access same variable in another controller. But its showing me value nil!!! I have checked that value was setup in the variable while setting up

Comment: What exactly are you sending to the /myroute action? Or in other words how to send the data to that action

Comment: I have the same problem, setting a value is not present anymore after redirecting on the method that set the session value in.